# cubic spline regression with sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cubic-spline

I want to regress very accurately a target which depends non-linearly from a single variable x. In my sklearn pipeline, I use:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(3, include_bias=False)), \
                     ('regr', ElasticNet(random_state=0))])
```

This appears to give similar results to `np.polyfit(x, y, 3)` in terms of accuracy. However, I can basically go to machine precision by using cubic splines. See figure below where I show the data and various fits, along with the residual errors. [Note: the example below has 50 samples. I have 2000 samples in reality]

I have two questions:

1. Any clue why `polyfit` or `polyfeat + Elasticnet` aren't able to reach the same level of accuracy?
2. Any example of target regression with cubic splines in `scikit-learn`?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
    %matplotlib inline
    
    data = pd.read_csv('example.txt') # added to this post below
    
    p = np.polyfit(data['x'], data['y'], 3)
    data['polyfit'] = np.poly1d(p)(data['x'])
    f = interp1d(data['x'], data['y'], kind='cubic')
    data['spline'] = f(data['x'])
    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
    
    axes[0].plot(data['x'], data['polyfit'],'.', label='polyfit')
    axes[0].plot(data['x'], data['spline'],'.', label='spline')
    axes[0].plot(data['x'], data['y'],'.', label='true')
    axes[0].legend()
    
    axes[1].plot(data['x'], data['polyfit']-data['y'],'.', label='error polyfit')
    axes[1].legend()
    
    axes[2].plot(data['x'], data['spline']-data['y'],'.', label='error spline')
    axes[2].legend()
    
    plt.show()
```

[image: comparison of various fits]

Here are the data:

example.txt:

```
    ,x,y
257,6.26028462060192,-1233.748349982897
944,4.557099191827032,928.1430280794456
1560,6.765081341690966,-1807.9090703632864
504,4.0015671921214775,1683.311523022658
1499,3.0496689401255783,3055.291788377236
1247,5.608726443314061,-441.9226126757499
1856,4.6124942196224845,845.129184983355
1495,1.273838638033053,5479.078773760113
1052,5.353775782315625,-115.14032709875217
247,2.6495185259267076,3656.7467318648232
1841,9.73337795053495,-4884.806993807511
1574,1.1772247845133335,5544.080005636716
1116,5.698561786140379,-555.3435567718
1489,4.184371293153768,1427.6922357286753
603,1.568868565047676,5179.156099377357
358,4.534081088923849,960.3983442022857
774,9.304809492028289,-4468.215701489676
1525,9.17423541311121,-4340.565494266174
1159,6.705834877066449,-1750.189447626367
1959,3.0431599461645207,3065.358649171256
1086,1.3861557136230234,5378.274828554064
81,4.728366950632029,682.7245723055514
1791,6.954198834068505,-2027.0414501796324
234,2.8672306789699844,3330.7282514295102
1850,2.0086469278742363,4603.0931759401155
1531,9.843164998128215,-4973.735518791005
903,1.534448692052103,5220.331847067942
1258,7.243723209152924,-2354.629822080041
645,2.3302780902754514,4128.077572586273
1425,3.295574067849755,2694.766296765896
311,2.3225198086033756,4152.206609684557
219,8.479436097125713,-3665.2515034579396
1917,7.1524135031820135,-2253.3455629418195
1412,6.79800860136838,-1861.3756670478142
705,1.9001265482939966,4756.283634364785
663,3.441268690856777,2489.7632239249424
1871,6.473544271091015,-1480.6593600880415
1897,8.217615163361007,-3386.5427698021977
558,6.609652057181176,-1634.1672307700298
553,5.679571371137544,-524.352981663938
1847,6.487178186324092,-1500.1891501936236
752,9.377368455681758,-4548.188126821915
1469,8.586759667609758,-3771.691600599668
1794,6.649801445466815,-1674.4870918398076
968,1.6226439291315056,5117.8804886837
108,3.0077346937655647,3118.0786841570025
96,6.278616413290749,-1245.4758811316083
994,7.631678455127069,-2767.3224262153176
871,2.6696610777085863,3630.02481913033
1405,9.209358577104299,-4368.622350004463
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former two methods for a single cubic equation to your data, but (as the name implies) `interp1d` *interpolates* the data with cubic splines: that is, there is a cubic curve for *each* consecutive pair of points, and so you are guaranteed a perfect fit (up to computational precision).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post a follow-up of my earlier question. It is possible to fit a model based on B-spline with a limited complexity (pre-defined number of splines -- not growing with the number of points as with interp1d) using scikit-learn. The following code is taken from [robust_splines_sklearn.py](https://gist.github.com/MMesch/35d7833a3daa4a9e8ca9c6953cbe21d4).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, ElasticNet

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def get_bspline_basis(knots, degree=3, periodic=False):
    """Get spline coefficients for each basis spline."""
    nknots = len(knots)
    y_dummy = np.zeros(nknots)

    knots, coeffs, degree = splrep(knots, y_dummy, k=degree,
                                      per=periodic)
    ncoeffs = len(coeffs)
    bsplines = []
    for ispline in range(nknots):
        coeffs = [1.0 if ispl == ispline else 0.0 for ispl in range(ncoeffs)]
        bsplines.append((knots, coeffs, degree))
    return bsplines

class BSplineFeatures(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, knots, degree=3, periodic=False):
        self.bsplines = get_bspline_basis(knots, degree, periodic=periodic)
        self.nsplines = len(self.bsplines)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        nsamples, nfeatures = X.shape
        features = np.zeros((nsamples, nfeatures * self.nsplines))
        for ispline, spline in enumerate(self.bsplines):
            istart = ispline * nfeatures
            iend = (ispline + 1) * nfeatures
            features[:, istart:iend] = splev(X, spline)
        return features

    
data = pd.read_csv('example.txt') 
knots = np.array([1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7.5, 10])

bspline_features = BSplineFeatures(knots, degree=3, periodic=False)
base_regressor = LinearRegression()


pipe1 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(3, include_bias=False)), \
                  ('regr', ElasticNet(random_state=0))])

pipe2 = Pipeline([('feature', bspline_features), \
                  ('regression', base_regressor)])

models = {"polyfit": pipe1, "spline": pipe2}
    
X = data['x'].to_numpy().reshape((data.shape[0], 1))
y = data['y']

for label, model in models.items():
    model.fit(X, y)
    data[label] = model.predict(X)
    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)

axes[0].plot(data['x'], data['polyfit'],'.', label='polyfit')
axes[0].plot(data['x'], data['spline'],'.', label='spline')
axes[0].plot(data['x'], data['y'],'.', label='true')
axes[0].legend()

axes[1].plot(data['x'], data['polyfit']-data['y'],'.', label='error polyfit')
axes[1].legend()

axes[2].plot(data['x'], data['spline']-data['y'],'.', label='error spline')
axes[2].legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Just noticed that features obtained from B-splines just made it into scikit-learn!
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/18368 with the class SplineTransformer

Comment: Here is a demo code for tensor spline regression with scikit-learn https://gist.github.com/ecm0/fe8966f9170409cfbc4f34c919462f98